# How to hide or show text(years old) if value(selectedPatient.age) is returned? React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hello I need to display years old on the screen only when I get the value from selectedPatient.age, visible or hidden

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PatientContext } from '../App';

const ContentHeader = () => {
    let { selectedPatient, setSidebarPatients, sidebarPatients } = useContext(PatientContext);
    const history = useHistory();

const deletePatient = async () => {
    const newSidebarPatients = sidebarPatients.filter(el => el.id != selectedPatient.id);
    setSidebarPatients(newSidebarPatients);
    history.push('/');
};

const pushEditComponent = () => {
    history.push('/patient/edit');
};

return (
    <div className='header'>
        <p className='firstname'>{selectedPatient.firstname}</p>
        <p className='lastname'>{selectedPatient.lastname}</p>
        <p className='age'>{selectedPatient.age} years old</p>

        <div> 
            <button onClick={pushEditComponent} className='edit-btn'>Edit</button>
            <button onClick={deletePatient} className='delete-btn'>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default ContentHeader;
```

[years old always visible.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZiIy.png)

Comment: you can consider applying some techniques from here https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

you conditional rendering here
Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

```
... 
return (
    <div className='header'>
        <p className='firstname'>{selectedPatient.firstname}</p>
        <p className='lastname'>{selectedPatient.lastname}</p>
        {selectedPatient.age? <p className='age'>{selectedPatient.age} years old</p>: null} 

        <div> 
            <button onClick={pushEditComponent} className='edit-btn'>Edit</button>
            <button onClick={deletePatient} className='delete-btn'>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
} 
...
```

Comment: can you please upvote the and mark answer as correct? . :)